# notify other nodes when a file is uploaded in ifps private network

Tags: distributed, p2p, ipfs

I created an IPFS private network. Whenever someone uploads a new file, all the nodes in the network should be notified. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: i don't think that IPFS provide somethings like that with the node, maybe there is somethings with the JS API or Go API

Answer (score 1):

You can look into the *pubsub* mechanism:

> First, you’ll need to enable the pubsub code. Make sure you’re running go-ipfs 0.4.5 or above. Once you have that version of ipfs installed, start the daemon with:
>
> ```sh
> ipfs daemon --enable-pubsub-experiment
> ```
>
> This will tell ipfs to create and enable the pubsub service. It also implies that you will only be able to use pubsub with other peers who choose to enable it.
>
> To subscribe to the topic foo, run:
>
> ```sh
> ipfs pubsub sub foo
> ```
>
> Now, any messages for the topic foo will print to your console.
>
> To publish a message to the topic foo, open up another terminal and run:
>
> ```sh
> ipfs pubsub pub foo "hello world"
> ```
>
> You should see "hello world" printed out in the first terminal.

Source: [Take a look at pubsub on IPFS](https://blog.ipfs.io/25-pubsub/)

Also see: [`ipfs name pubsub` | Command-line reference | IPFS Docs](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/cli/#ipfs-name-pubsub)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will check it out.